# Large object (ntext and image) cannot be used in ORDER BY clauses

Tags: c#, code-first, sql-server-ce-4

I wanted to change my code-first project to SQL Server Compact 4.0.

But I have a problem with following LINQ expression

```
db.Test.OrderBy(t => t.Name).ToList()
```

It throws the following error

> Large object (ntext and image) cannot be used in ORDER BY clauses

Is there a way to tell code-first to create a `nvarchar` type for the `Name` field instead of the `ntext` type when creating the database?

Comment: *"ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead. "* - [The MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: that applies to the **full** versions of SQL Server - this is about SQL Server **Compact** which doesn't have `nvarchar(max)` support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Decorate the Name property of your entity class with this attribute:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This disabled my CodeFirst Migration. I got following error: Sequence contains no matching element

Comment: Yeah of course, you should use nvarchar instead of varchar, my mistake :-)